# Express Multer File Upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am trying to use Multer file upload in my React/Express application.  But, I am getting an error that says that the file object is undefined.  I have moved all of my Express server api functions into their own file, which has been working fine.  I would like to keep the file upload API function in the same file as the rest of the API functions.  This is what I have:

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const config = require('config');
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const PORT = config.get('app_port') || 8000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/api/meshnodes", require("./routes/myCrudRoutes"));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
app.use(errorHandler);
```

**myCrudRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const {uploadFile} = require('../controllers/myCrudContoller')
router.post('/catalog/files/upload/',  uploadFile)
module.exports = router
```

**myCrudControllers.js**

```
const ansyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const multer = require("multer");
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let extension = getFileExtention(file.mimetype);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + "." + extension);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const uploadFile = (upload.single("File"), (req,res, next)=>{  
   console.log("got file2 ")
   const file = req.body;
   console.log(req)
   if (!file) {
     const error = new Error("No File");
     error.httpStatusCode = 400;
     return next(error);
   }
   console.log("server upload ")
});
```

I believe the issue is with my myCrudControllers.js uploadFile function.  If I have this same functionality placed directly in my server.js file, like this:

```
app.post(
  "/catalog/files/upload",
  upload.single("File"),
  (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file;
   //...
```

It works fine, but I want to be consistent in where I have my API functions.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my code and this works:

First, I created a helper file:

**uploader.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
let storage = multer.diskStorage({    
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {       
      cb(null, process.env.REACT_APP_UPLOAD_LOCATION);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      let extension = getFileExtention(file.mimetype);
      cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + "." + extension);
    },
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

**myCrudRoutes.js**

```
const uploadHelper = require('../helpers/uploader');
router.post('/catalog/files/upload', uploadHelper.upload.single('File'), uploadFile);
```

**myCrudControllers.js**

```
const uploadFile = ansyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{   
  const file = req.file;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error("No File");
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return error;
  }
  //other stuff
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
}

);
```